# ul tag will not use list-style after using a reset

Tags: html, css

So, I'm looking for clarification on why a reset is taking precedence over my override.

I have a `ul` tag I want centered and I want the list-style to be a solid disk. When I look in the dev tools, I see the reset is crossed out and my rule is active (no line through it). I still don't get the disks showing until I uncheck the striked-out reset rule.

My understanding is that if a rule has a strike through it, then it's not applied. Is this wrong?

Please see screenshots. What am I missing?

```
<ul style="display:inline-block !important;list-style:disc;line-height:1.5;">
  <li><h6>something</h6></li>
  <li><h6>something</h6></li>
</ul>
```

This will not get me the list-style until I remove the checkmark from the invalidated reset rule. Again, please see image.

Please see screenshots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBNEz.jpg)

Comment: You did not post any screenshots, also please include your code in the message.

Comment: maybe in general selector or somewhere in your css you use list-style: none that's why it's happening

Comment: It looks like the system doesn't trust me yet so it discarded my image. I must be too new.

Comment: Okay I was able to post an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with their list-style not showing, if you are using a css reset file like, Eric Meyer's, that file will "reset" the `li` tag to a block level element.

What you need is `display:list-item`. It's not by default a block element so you need to specify its default behavior for it to show the list-item.